# The method was called on null error in flutter

Tags: android, api, flutter, http, dart

I need your help, below is my simple code trying to get data from API, I'm using flutter and postman for testing I don't know what exactly is wrong but i'm getting the error (The method [] was called on null.) Anyone who can help!!

```
class FetchTarget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  // _FetchTargetState createState() => _FetchTargetState();
  // return fetchTarget();
  // };

  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _FetchTargetState();
  }
}

class _FetchTargetState extends State<FetchTarget> {
  fetchTarget() async {
    var res = await http.get("http://192.168.1.00:8000/api/taarifa");
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var obj = json.decode(res.body);
      return obj;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchTarget();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchTarget(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot != null) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.data[index]['name']),
                  subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index]['date']),
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

in the end i expect it to return lists of taarifa and display in in listview in my mobile

Comment: Instead of checking `snapshot != null` check `snapshot.hasData`

Answer (score 0):

Rember that for a correct implementation of FutureBuilder you must pay attention that the async method must not called more than once.
Moreover I noticed that you don't return anything if there is an error.
That could be the problem:

This is a simple solution:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FetchTarget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _FetchTargetState();
  }
}

class _FetchTargetState extends State<FetchTarget> {
  Future _fetched;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _fetched = _fetchTarget();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<dynamic> _fetchTarget() async {
    var res = await http.get("http://192.168.1.00:8000/api/taarifa");
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var obj = json.decode(res.body);
      return obj;
    }else {
     return <String, dynamic>{} ; //an empty map as error, but you must check better if the http get returned an exception

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _fetched,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                itemCount : snapshot.data.length, 
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.data[index]['name']),
                  subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index]['date']),
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Another better solution is to use Flutter Hooks.

Here after a little example:

```
class MyWidget extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final future = useMemoized(() {
     
      _fetchTarget(); 
    });
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: future,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return ....;
      }
    );
  }
}
```